# document.form.submit() não da para validar

Tags: javascript, html5

Galera fiz uma função que que quando o usuário clica sobre um botão, ele chama a ação `document.form.submit()`, ate ai tudo bem, ele envia o formulário normalmente. Mas no `<form>` coloquei o `onsubmit="return validarFormulario();"` mas ele não está chamando esta função e nao gera erro no console, apenas nao realiza a função. Como faço para validar o formulário usando este método?

**index.html**

```
<div class="cabecalho-pagina">
        <div class="titulo">
            <div class="icon-pagina">
                <img src="<?=_URL_;?>/admin/img/icon-48-article-add.png" alt="Artigo">
            </div>
            <span>Notícia: [Novo]</span>
        </div>

        <div class="menus-pagina">
            <a onclick="document.formulario.submit();">
                <span class="icone-menu-pagina icone-salvar"></span>
                <span>Salvar</span>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <span class="icone-menu-pagina icone-cancelar"></span>
                <span>Cancelar</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="conteudo-pagina">
        <form action="" method="post" id="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="formulario" name="formulario" onsubmit="return validarFormulario();">
            <input type="text" name="titulo" id="titulo" class="titulo" placeholder="Título da notícia" required/>
            <input type="text" name="data" id="data" class="data" value="<?=date("d-m-Y h:i:s");?>" required/>

            <label>
                Publicado:
                <select class="publicado" name="publicado" id="">
                    <option value="1" required>Sim</option>
                    <option value="1">Não</option>
                </select>
            </label>

            <textarea class="conteudo" id="conteudo" name="conteudo" placeholder="Conteudo da notícia" required></textarea>

            <input type="file" name="imagem" class="imagem" id="imagem" accept=".jpg,.png,.gif">

        </form>

    </div>
```

**funcoes.js**

```
function validarFormulario(){
    if(document.getElementById("titulo").value==""){
        alert("Preencha o campo de titulo");
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Tens de colocar mais código, senõ não dá para saber o que pode ser o problema...

Comment: Poste a função validarFormulario.

Comment: @Sergio adicionei os códigos.

Comment: @Laerte adicionei os códigos.

Comment: Uma dúvida você colocou o script funcoes.js no head ou no final do body?

Comment: @Laerte tentei nos dois casos, nenhum deles funcionou. Dei um `console.log("teste");` dentro do arquivo, e eles esta funcionando normal, parece que a função `onsubmit` do `form` que não esta funcionando.

Comment: Você quer: quando a pessoa clica no link "Salvar" dar submit no form mas primeiro validando se o retorno da função é true?

Comment: @Laerte isso mesmo.

Comment: A função é chamada, mas o `if` dá sempre `false` porque o campo titulo é obrigatório e nunca fica vazio. O que está errado? Como fazes o submit da função? -> https://jsfiddle.net/9h9pxeay/

Comment: @Sergio aqui eu chamo a função submit `<a onclick="document.formulario.submit();">
                <span class="icone-menu-pagina icone-salvar"></span>
                <span>Salvar</span>
            </a>`

Comment: Você não vai ter nenhum botão pra enviar  o formulário? Apenas o link né? Você pode colocar o submit() na função de validação?

Comment: @Laerte sim, apenas no link. Como coloco o submit na validação?

Comment: Veja se minha resposta atende ao que você espera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu removi o atributo "required" para fins de demonstração, passei a chamada da validação pro link "Salvar" já que o formulário não vai ter nenhum botão de submit. Se sua função não entrar em nenhuma das validações e retornar falso o retorno padrão é um alert e depois ele envia seu formulário, o atributo `onsubmit` no seu formulário não faz sentido nesse caso onde a chamada é feita via Javascript

```js
function validarFormulario() {
  // validações
  if (document.getElementById("titulo").value == "") {
    alert("Preencha o campo de titulo");
    return false;
  }
  alert("Enviou");
  document.formulario.submit();
}
```

```html
<div class="menus-pagina">
  <a href="#" onclick="validarFormulario()">
    <span class="icone-menu-pagina icone-salvar"></span>
    <span>Salvar</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="icone-menu-pagina icone-cancelar"></span>
    <span>Cancelar</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="conteudo-pagina">
  <form action="" method="post" id="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="formulario" name="formulario">
    <input type="text" name="titulo" id="titulo" class="titulo" placeholder="Título da notícia" />
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="data" id="data" class="data" placeholder="Data da Postagem" />
    <br>
    <label>
      Publicado:
      <select class="publicado" name="publicado" id="">
        <option value="1">Sim</option>
        <option value="1">Não</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    <br>
    <textarea class="conteudo" id="conteudo" name="conteudo" placeholder="Conteudo da notícia"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="file" name="imagem" class="imagem" id="imagem" accept=".jpg,.png,.gif">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: funcionou. Valeu!